# How to get the Drawable name from imageview in android and get it's String name for comparing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

I have two drawable ***apple*** and  **a** how to get the drawable name in my code and compare that they starts with same alphabet

### Community edited question

Questioner is actually seeking for 2 problems-

1. at first he wants to get the drawable id from the imageview id. (thw drawable which is showing in the imageview)
2. then he wants to get the drawable name from that obtained drawable id in step-1.

Comment: Did you try `String name = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageResID);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer

### For step-1

There is no direct way. You need to save the drawable id in the imageview's `Tag` via `setTag()`. then you can retrieve by `getTag()` of the imageview.

### Step-2

you should get the image name by

```
String imageName1 = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.apple);
// now imageName1 should contain "apple".

String imageName2 = context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.a);
// now imageName2 should contain "a".

if(imageName1.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == imageName2.toLowerCase().charAt(0))

{

  // starting character 'a' is matching

}
```

Comment: i mam getting the drawablest that are 26 on image view randomly so i have to check the drawablename by putting drawable id ...for 26 so is their any way that i can get the drawable name by just imageview id and get which drawable is aatached to that imageview

Comment: let us be clear, you want to get the drawable id first  from the imageview id,  then you want to get the drawable name from that obtained drawable id. are we clear about your needs?

Comment: my current answer should serve your 2nd part.

Comment: but how to get the drawable id by imageview id ??

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh SO if not for spoon-feeding, please show what you've tried using the provided answer.

Comment: To my best knowledge, there is no SDK supported direct way to get the drawable id from the imageview. you should share your research now with the answerers.

Comment: @Ashutoshsingh, accept my updated answer if you don't find any other way to do that. And if you find anything, then please do share in the post with all of us.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
String name1 = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.drawable_id_1);
String name2 = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.drawable_id_2);

if (name1.startsWith("a") && name2.startsWith("a")) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: yes but how to get the drawable id by its imageview id  ...because i have 26 drawable so ...to do this staticallly it will be lengthy

Answer (score 0):

Get the full resource name via `getResources().getResourceName(R.drawable.XXXX)`. This will return you a string in the form `package:type/entry`.

For example my project has the package `com.test.app` and a drawable called `apple.png` in my resources. Calling the method I mentioned the result will be:

```
com.test.app:drawable/apple
```

As you want to compare images in the same project, you can easily truncate the part until the actual name, as it'll be the same for all your images.