# get displayed drawable name from imageview

Tags: imageview, drawable

am trying to create an ImageView that displays various drawable images, i would like to get the drawable name for the image it is displaying. so i nid to control an event based on the drawable name of the imageview. any help? thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29488340/how-to-get-the-drawable-name-from-imageview-in-android-and-get-its-string-name

Comment: may be i wasnt clear i nid to control an event based on the drawable name of the imageview. that other question just shows how to get the name. any ideas? thank you